# CSS: Display image only

Tags: css, media-queries

For reasons of printing I would like to display an image only and hide the rest of the page. I tried this:

```
<style media="print">
    body {display: none;}
    .print {display: inline;}
</style>
<body>
    <!-- some stuff before -->
    <img class="print" src="myimage.jpg">
    <!-- some stuff after -->
</body>
```

but it doesn't work: Nothing is displayed. IMO .print is more specific than body and thus should have a higher priority. Using * instead of body didn't work either.

Comment: try `print {display: block;}`

Comment: When a parent is hidden, all the children nodes are hidden regardless of their `display` value. You will have to hide all children, except the images, of the body element, using `body *:not(.print) { display: none; }`

Comment: The class is more specific than the element, but if the parent (body) is not displayed, it doesn't matter what styles are show on the child, they can't be seen. If there's a picture on the page of a book, and you rip out the page, the picture is no longer in the book.

Comment: @DBS This has nothing to do with cascading. If it is indeed a cascading effect, assigning the print image an ID should technically override the `display: none` property of the parent. But this will not happen.

Comment: @Terry Perhaps poor choice of words given the context, my point was a parent not being displayed cascades down to all children. Not the css property, that can be overwritten, but the actual fact is cannot be seen.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, now I understand things better. body *:not(.print) { display: none; } is a fine trick that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<style media="print">
    body > * {display: none;}
    .print {display: block;}
</style>
```

You cannot hide the whole body, as images are contained in the body. Also, I'm not sure, but I think that you need to display images as blocks in order to print them.

Comment: Here's a one-liner that does the same, in browsers that support the `:not()` pseudo-selector: `body *:not(.print) { display: none; }`

Comment: Yeah, but you should always consider that a lot of people still use IE9

Comment: IE9 supports `:not()`. Only IE8 (and below) doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for this info. body *:not(.print) { display: none; } is a fine trick that does exactly what I need.